# How do i upgrade cloud.appwrite.io to the latest version...?

Tags: appwrite

I'am using Appwrite for a long time now, but I recently got to know about the 'relationship' feature in the database. So i wanted to try it in my flutter app but I'm currently using appwrite's cloud version for my app, is there any way I can upgrade appwrite cloud..? Thanks in advance...

I'm expecting a solution to upgrade appwrite cloud or a future date when it will be available for me to get the upgrade...

Answer (score 0):

So cloud is on 1.1.2 as of now and we expect it to upgrade to 1.2 in few days and few days after that to 1.3
Relationships are in beta and were introduced in 1.3 so to be used in cloud, we would have to wait till the upgrade.
Hope this helps.
Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow and thanks for answering your first question.

Answer (score 0):

They've updated it recently. It now works with version 1.4.3[image]